# How do I disengage the grappling hook?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have recently acquired the grappling hook in Terraria for iOS. With the touch interface, I cannot seem to figure out how to disengage the hook once I have grappled onto something. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to jump to disengage on PC... I think. I don't think there is a specific key to disengage though.

Comment: @Reafexus Thanks for the tip, but this question specifically relates to iOS.

Comment: I meant to add that I don't know about iOS but I guess I spaced out in the middle of that sentence. I just was implying, if anything, there would be less functionality on iOS than on PC and it is not on PC so there's no reason for it to be on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disengage the grappling hook to a different surface, use the grappling hook again somewhere else. To disengage it so you can move normally, just jump! :)

Comment: So there's no way to just drop from or let go of a surface?

Comment: If you mean a specific disengage command, as far as I know, no. I could be wrong, however.

Comment: It's not possible to disengage the hook without jumping or hooking something else even in the PC version.